# problems: python manage.py syncdb in windows 7 with mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-syncdb

I am using python django with mysql.I am following all the rules given in the tutorial but still then um getting error.Problem specification is given below.
my database setting in setting.py is like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
```

after running syncdb command i'm getting error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_
signal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 9, in
 <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <modul
e>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __geta
ttr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 93, in __getitem
__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 27, in load_back
end
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17
, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No mo
dule named MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to install python-mysql it can get from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

---

### or you can use sqlite3 it is very simple

```
import os
path=os.path.dirname(__file__)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': path+'/django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i need to work with mysql for customer requirement.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan the error is becuse you did not installed python-mysql package. you can download the binary setupfile for windows from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python